# Azure: Access to https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant-id}/saml2 with Bearer Token

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, saml, confluence-rest-api

My requirement:

- I have a confluence instance connected to Azure AD with SAML Connector for Single Sign On
- It should be possible to send API calls to that confluence by an application where the users are already signed in (with their Azure account)
- Confluence (on premise) is not supporting bearer "access_token"s, just basic auth and cookies.

My way to go:

- Ask the confluence for a SAMLRequest.
- Post the SAMLRequest to Azure with valid credentials and get SAMLResponse
- Post SAMLResponse to confluence and get a cookie
- Call API with that cookie

I think that should work. But i am new to authorizations and azure.

My problem:

- I POST to https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant-id}/saml2 with my SAMLRequest in Body and a valid bearer access_token in HTTP Header ("Authorization" field), but I always get a "SIGN IN" page as response.
  I thought my access_token is my key to login without a login prompt.

Any ideas for this? Maybe my way to go is absolutely incorrect. I don't know. That's the way I access the API in web browser.

Here two pictures of my requests:

[GET access_token from Azure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KshL3.png)

[POST SAMLRequest to Azure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LcEDj.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We bought some 3rd Party tool that handles access_token for Confluence REST API.

What technically is necessary for new REST endpoints:
- Grab the Azure access_token
- Send the access_token to https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me
- get the answer to which user this access_token belongs
- change the context to that user

I have no time to implement this on my own. So the Addon was okay for us. google for "REST API confluence oauth" and you will get it.

Comment: Could you post some more details on this? I am trying to do the same, but for another system where I will not be able to buy a plugin. What precisely do you mean by "change context to that user"? Could you post an example of the final request to the saml-endpoint?

Comment: I set my Endpoint to "allow anonymous access" and using frameworks to validate the access_token (you can find a lot of information with keyword "JSON web token (jwt)").
I validate the validity of the token and compare it with my "validIssuers". So I check if the token was signed by one of my connected azure systems.
Then I read the upn from the claims of the access_token and change the context of the request to that user who is referenced in this token. That's easy for confluence because there is some powerful API to do this. I hope that's helpful to you.